# Rails 5.2: form_with requires "local: false" for AJAX requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I just upgraded from Rails 5.1 to 5.2.  I have good test coverage with an app that has been in production for several months without issue.

I have been using `form_with` for a few months with Rails 5.1.  The default for `form_with` is that all forms are AJAX by default and must be specified `local: true` in order to have normal HTTP POST requests.

After the upgrade to Rails 5.2 (I followed the upgrade guidelines), I ran into a situation where some of my forms are no longer submitting as AJAX requests unless I specifically add `local: false` to them.

Scroll to the end of the code snippet to see the additional `local: false` that works.  The code is taken directly from the app without alteration.

```
# This will not work and submits a normal HTTP POST
<%= form_with model: @team_member_type, url: [:settings, @team_member_type], class: "dialog-container", id: "team_member_type-dialog", data: { closable: "false" } do |form| %>

# This will work and submits an AJAX request
<%= form_with model: @team_member_type, url: [:settings, @team_member_type], class: "dialog-container", id: "team_member_type-dialog", data: { closable: "false" }, local: true do |form| %>
```

When I submit the form WITHOUT the `local: false` declaration, I get:

```
Authenticated::Settings::TeamMemberTypesController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []
```

Again, the only change I'm making is manually adding `local: false` to the form to force it to be remote.

The docs say that `local: false` is the **default**, so I shouldn't have to specify it manually.

What am I missing here?

Note that AJAX links with `remote: true` are working just fine; it's only forms that are not submitting AJAX by default.

**Update**

Doing some digging, it looks like it may be an issue when I upgraded to 5.1.  I couldn't find the `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb` file, and that would have had the default flag to set `form_with` to remote.  Since that file didn't exist when I upgraded to 5.2, it didn't pull those new default configs over.  I'll update this question if I verify that was indeed the issue.

**Update 2**

Yeah, verified that the issue was I didn't have the `config/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb` file that would have copied these config values over.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was I didn't have the upgrade config files from Rails 5.1 that would have copied over new defaults. Rails eventually removed that in 5.1 (or 5.2?) and uses a `config.load_defaults VERSION` instead, which loads all upgraded config to the specified version.

One of the dangers of upgrading one version at a time, things changed between my upgrade from 5.1 to 5.2! I recommend reading all release notes for ALL versions ahead of time, not just one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrade from Rails 5.1 to Rails 5.2

> ActionController::UnknownFormat request.formats: ["text/html"]
>   Controlle is missing a template for this request format and variant.

form_with submit didn't work remotely. It works only with local: false parameter

Here are the relevant lines from my `config/application.rb` file:

```
module RailsStarterKit
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 5.2
```